# standard memory coverage of android app

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

what should be the maximum memory can be used by an standard android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29)

> Return the approximate per-application memory class of the current device. This gives you an idea of how hard a memory limit you should impose on your application to let the overall system work best. The returned value is in megabytes; the baseline Android memory class is 16 (which happens to be the Java heap limit of those devices); some device with more memory may return 24 or even higher numbers.

So basically, from 16mb to whatever.